# jQuery appending element too many times

Tags: jquery, append

I am creating shortlisting functionality, on `.click()` it appends the attributes from the anchor tag into a tables `tbody`.

This data is display from a db in a php while loop, I currently have 3 records in the db.

All is working fine apart from one thing, it is appending them the same amount of time as there are records in the database. so for example I have 3 records, it's appending it 3 times to the

HTML:

```
<a href="#"class="add_to_shortlist" cadidate_email="<?php echo $cadidate_email; ?>" candidate_phone="<?php echo $cadidate_phone; ?>" candidate_name="<?php echo $cadidate_name; ?>" candid="<?php echo $cv_id; ?>" candidate_cv="candidate_database/<?php echo $cv_link; ?>" >Add to shortlist</a
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.add_to_shortlist').click(function(){

        var candidate_id = $(this).attr('candid');  
        var candidate_name = $(this).attr("candidate_name");
        var cadidate_email = $(this).attr("cadidate_email");    
        var candidate_phone = $(this).attr("candidate_phone");  
        var candidate_cv = $(this).attr("candidate_cv");    


        var newRowContent = "<tr><td>" + candidate_id +" </td><td>" + candidate_name + "</td><td>" + cadidate_email + "</td><td>" + candidate_phone + "</td><td><a target='_blank' href="+ candidate_cv +">View</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete_shortlisted_row'>remove</a></td></tr>";   

        $("#shortlist_table tbody").append(newRowContent);  

    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE TRY THIS IT MAY HELP YOU

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="add_to_shortlist" cadidate_email="<?php echo $cadidate_email; ?>" candidate_phone="<?php echo $cadidate_phone; ?>" candidate_name="<?php echo $cadidate_name; ?>" candid="<?php echo $cv_id; ?>" candidate_cv="candidate_database/<?php echo $cv_link; ?>" >Add to shortlist</a>
<table class="table table-condensed">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Candidate Id</th> 
                                                            <th>Candidate Name</th>
                                                            <th>Candidate Email</th>
                                                            <th>Candidate Phone</th>
                                                            <th>Candidate CV</th>

                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody id="cand">
                                                    </tbody>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.add_to_shortlist').click(function(){

        var candidate_id = $(this).attr('candid');  
        var candidate_name = $(this).attr("candidate_name");
        var cadidate_email = $(this).attr("cadidate_email");    
        var candidate_phone = $(this).attr("candidate_phone");  
        var candidate_cv = $(this).attr("candidate_cv");    


        var newRowContent = "<tr><td>" + candidate_id +" </td><td>" + candidate_name + "</td><td>" + cadidate_email + "</td><td>" + candidate_phone + "</td><td><a target='_blank' href="+ candidate_cv +">View</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete_shortlisted_row'>remove</a></td></tr>";   

        $("#cand").append(newRowContent);  

    });     
});
```

Comment: Nothing has been changed. Apart from adding `table-condensed`

Comment: please go through this link https://jsfiddle.net/susanadhikary/gteecn0x/2/

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: i cannot get your problem properly please let the proper description what the aim of your program

Comment: as I said in the description it is appending the element 3 times. I couldn't have been clearer in the description. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: please check the link once again and leave the comment there